# Why does adding (1) at the end of the Split fucntion clear the type mismatch error?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a macro that finds a column header and select all the contents below that header. However, I didn't want to use `.end(xldown)` and wanted to used `.end(xlup)` to prevent issues with an empty column. But I was faced with an issue that the column where the header is located is dynamic.

I looked around and found a code that uses split to find the column letter:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim rngHeader As Range
Dim rngHeadReq As Range

Set rngHeader = Range("A1:AL1")
Set rngHeadReq = rngHeader.Find("Adjustment Operation Type")

col = rngHeadReq.Address
colAddress = Split(col, "$")(1)

MsgBox colAddress

End Sub
```

The msgbox returns the correct column letter. I looked up split and it seems straightforward, what I don't understand is the (1) used by the coder that I copied it off. When I remove (1), vba is giving me a type mismatch error. Looking at the parameters of split, it looks like it's not part of it.

What does (1) actually do?

Comment: Split returns array and (1) gets the second item in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what you are looking at is a shortcut in programming. Here is the code fully spelled out (in a dummy-sub for you to copy and run for yourself):

```
Sub tmpSO()

Dim tmp As String
Dim arr() As String

tmp = "$5$m$$a$1$"
arr = Split(tmp, "$")
Debug.Print arr(1)

End Sub
```

When you `Split()` a string then you are essentially converting it into an array (or list) using the given separator. In the above example, the string is separated using the `$` sign. So, the first item (before the first `$` is `""` because there is nothing before the first `$` sign. The second item is the number `5`. Since VBA is counting the list starting with item `(0)` the second item is `(1)`.

Here is a screenshot of the code at run-time with an added watch to `arr`:

[image]

You can clearly see the listor `arr` down below and the items with the index numbers next to it.

Note, that `Split()` will always gernerate arrays starting with item `(0)` no matter if you use `Option Base 1` or not at the start of your module.

Personal note: I am also not a big fan of abbreviations / shortcuts when coding. That makes the code harder to read and understand for newcomers. So, I'd code it the long / extended way as illustrated in the sample above instead of using the given abbreviation.

Comment: This is amazing, thank you for breaking it down for me! I would never think that it was used as an array.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the column letter?

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim rngHeader As Range
    Dim rngHeadReq As Range
    Dim rngDesired As Range
    Dim col As Long

    Set rngHeader = Range("A1:AL1")
    Set rngHeadReq = rngHeader.Find("Adjustment Operation Type")

    If Not rngHeadReq Is Nothing Then
        col = rngHeadReq.Column
        Set rngDesired = Range(Cells(1, col), Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp))
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I was thinking of something along the lines of `Range(colAddress & "10000").end(xlup)`. Turns out I can't easily do that as it's giving me an object required error. Your solution is way more elegant than what I had in mind.  But then again, why does it give me an error?

Comment: @BananaSyrup - What is the actual statement that gives the "object required" error?

Comment: I replaced the msgbox in my original code with `lRow = Range(colAddress & "10000").End(xlUp)` and tried to select it using `lRow.Select`. `lRow.Select` is giving me the object required error. Did I fail to properly define the range to select?

Comment: @BananaSyrup In order to assign the last used cell to `lRow`, you should have declared `lRow` as a `Range` object (i.e. `Dim lRow As Range`) and you need to then `Set` the object (i.e. `Set lRow = Range(colAddress & "10000").End(xlUp)`).  But that variable name makes me think you were trying to just store the row, i.e. `Dim lRow As Long` and then `lRow = Range(colAddress & "10000").End(xlUp).Row`.  But if that was the case, you wouldn't try to `Select` the row, you might use `lRow` in something like `Range(colAddress & lRow)`.

Comment: I was trying to select it just to test if I can properly select the last row. If it works, I would then do something like `rngFound = Range(rngHeadReq.Offset(1), lRow)` to select all the contents below header that I was looking for. Using 'Set' and defining the variable did help solve the issue with my current code. However, I would be abandoning my current code as it feels and looks clunky but it was a great learning experience. Thank you very much, I hope I can upvote you more as you went out of your way to explain it to me.